# To clear multiple controls

Tags: c#, winforms

hello
 In my Form I had used multiple container such as panel,group box.and as per my requirement i have to clear all the controls which are reside in container. For this i have  wrote a code as follows:-

```
foreach (Control  x in ControlContainer.Controls)//Error
{
    if (x is System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)
        ((TextBox)x).Text  = String.Empty;

    else  (x is System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)
    {
        ((ComboBox)x).SelectedIndex = -1;
        ((TextBox)x).Text = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

But its not working properly, i'm receiving error like:'object' does not contain a definition for 'Controls'

please help

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471927/find-references-to-the-object-in-runtime

Comment: Can you provide the declaration of the controlContainer object ..

Comment: if in both scenarios you have to set textbox.text to empty then why not keep it outside the condition if else and for error specify the declaration statements also then scenario will be more clear.Show the error message also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat recursive example from [ASP.NET Forums](http://forums.asp.net/p/1529134/3697190.aspx):

```
public static void ClearTxtBox(Control control)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
            (TextBox)ctrl.Text = "";
         if (ctrl.HasControls())   
             ClearTxtBox(ctrl);
    }
}
```

I don't think the `ControlContainer` returns the controls in the way you think.

Answer (score 0):

What is the declared type for ControlContainer?  Judging by the error, it is "object".  Most containers inherit from System.Windows.Controls.Panel, so you may be able to get by with:

```
Panel panel = ControlContainer as Panel;
foreach (Control x in panel.Children) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
 foreach (Control item in (groupBox1 as Control).Controls)
        {
            if (item is TextBox)
            {
                item.Text = "";
            }
            if (item is ComboBox)
            {
                (item as ComboBox).SelectedIndex = -1;
                (item as ComboBox).Text = "";

            }
        }
```

It could be groupBox1  or panel or any other using Control as a base.